# Insert php content into an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I currently have:

```
<iframe src="/index2.php" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">   </iframe>
```

I would like to instead insert the php content into the empty iframe using javascript. The content in index2.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../opt/lampp/htdocs/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

My goal is to eliminate index2.php file and directly include its content in the iframe. My understanding is pretty limited of how and if this could happen. I appreciate all help. Something like this

```
<iframe content=<?php
 $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../opt/lampp/htdocs/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/yii.php';  $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();....></iframe>
```

The code must be placed within the iframe to keep the domain masked.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2">
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<iframe src="/index2.php" frameborder="0"     style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">        </iframe>

</html>
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: When you say "PHP content", do you mean that right now the iframe is showing the result of the PHP code, and you want it to show the PHP source code instead?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have been really struggling with this. I would like to get rid of src='index2.php' and directly insert the above mentioned code into the iframe using javascript.

Comment: Is expected result text of `index2.php` within `iframe` element ?

Comment: I don't get how that could work. All PHP is executed before the page is send to the client. All JavaScript is executed after, so any PHP inserted with JS will not execute . You can however connect to other PHP scripts via AJAX.

Comment: I am currently linking to index2.php. I want to eliminate index2.php altogether and insert what used be in index2.php directly into the iframe using javascript. I am hoping it will give the exact same results.

Comment: This is getting kind of long and unwieldy...Sam, can you move more detail into the actual question and not the comments area?

Comment: Though you can store PHP code in a string in JavaScript and insert it into an element using innerHTML, the code will not be executed. All PHP runs on the server and all JavaScript DOM manipulation is executed on the client side. Why not insert the content from the server either by pasting the PHP code directly into your index file or with PHP include? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: How could I then pass it into the iframe? That code has to execute within the iframe for the masking to properly occur.

Comment: Why would you need an iframe element?

Comment: The iframe element is how I am keeping the domain masked. That code puts the website inside the iframe. See the full code in edit.

Comment: Load the page with php and echo out the html.

Comment: That's not a problem. How to place the code in iframe is.

Comment: Ok but the aproach that you are trying can not be done. The iframe src attribute will have to point to a url, not a string of content, and even if it could then PHP code can only be executed before any JavaScript. There are better options to mask urls. One could be to rewrite urls in the .htaccess file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Thank you. That; however, won't protect the iframe src upon being viewed. True?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React.

```
import * as React from 'react';


interface Props {
}

class Test extends React.Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props, state) {
        super(props, state);
        this.iframeRef = React.createRef();
    }

    iframeRef = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.iframeRef);
        if (this.iframeRef) {
            this.iframeRef.current.contentDocument.write("<h1>Hello World !!!</h1>");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <iframe ref={this.iframeRef} className="w-100"></iframe>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

For JS, get the iframe
using `document.querySelector()`

and use `contentDocument.write("<h1>Hello World !!!</h1>")`